# Node.js - process.nextTick and parseJSON

Tags: json, node.js, performance, parsing, event-loop

What's the most performant way to parse JSON in Node.js?

What's the advantage of using process.nextTick and slightly delaying the answer in the following snippet and shouldn't the whole try/catch be encapsulated into `process.nextTick`?

```
function parseJSON(json, done) {
     try {
         var result = JSON.parse(json);
         process.nextTick(function() { done(null, result); });
     } catch (err) {
         process.nextTick(function() { done(err); });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, because `JSON.parse` is synchronous, there's no point in using a callback.

These two blocks of code essentially do the same thing. The bottom one is more efficient:

```
parseJSON(json, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        //ERROR
    }
    else {
        //PARSED
    }
});
```

vs

```
try {
    var result = JSON.parse(json);
    //PARSED
}
catch (e) {
    //ERROR
}
```

---

Now onto your actual question(s):

> What's the advantage of using process.nextTick...

Basically there is no "advantage" except that if you don't use process.nextTick then your function call becomes more synchronous. Take this example for instance:

```
console.log('1');
parseJSON(json, function(err, result) {
    console.log('parsed');
});
console.log('2');
```

When using `process.nextTick` you'll get this output:

```
1
2
parsed
```

This happens because `process.nextTick` puts the callback function at the end of the event loop. Meaning it'll let other things happen first then execute the callback.

If you didn't use `process.nextTick` then you'd get this output:

```
1
parsed
2
```

This happens because `parseJSON` won't exit until the callback is called.

Both versions are valid, but with callbacks you usually to want them to be truly asynchronous.

---

As for the try-catch, it's fine where it's at if you're trying to catch errors coming from `JSON.parse`. Since you appear to want to handle the errors (because you're passing the error parameter to the callback if it throws an exception) then I'd say it's correct as is.

Comment: in the try/catch, result should be delcared before. Otherwise it s detroy after the end of the try scope.

Comment: It's referenced inside process.nextTick... I just tried it and it worked as I expected: The callback got the correct parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all
. process.nextick is async... Try catch may not work as you expext.. JSON.parse is preferred way to parse json string

Answer (score 0):

--> What's the most performant way to parse JSON in Node.js?

JSON stream probably, becasue of the low memory footprint.

See the work done by dominictarr or mafintosh

https://github.com/mafintosh/json-format-stream

https://github.com/mafintosh/through-json

https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream